# No soy capaz de hacer dos subconsultas para un UPDATE en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, update, subconsultas

Me he encontrado un ejercicio donde necesitaba actualizar una tabla para que un numero creciese a 20. El problema es que necesito hacer dos subconsultas, una para el ID_Exp y otra para el ID_Museo para que haya esa actualizacion.

En todos los sitios que buscaba los ejemplos que ponian era solamente el de una subconsulta. He aqui lo que he intentado sin exito.

lo que me pide el ejercicio es exactamente 'La exposición “Hablando con las manos” que se está dando en el museo Guggenheim aumenta su duración en 20 días.'

```
SET NDIAS = sum(NDIAS+20)
WHERE ME.ID_Exp = (Select ME.ID_Exp FROM ME, e
                    WHERE ME.ID_Exp=E.ID_Exp
                    AND e.Nombre = 'Hablando con las manos')
AND me.ID_Museo = (Select ME.ID_Museo FROM ME, m
                    WHERE me.ID_Museo=m.ID_Museo
                    AND m.Nombre = 'Guggenheim');
```

Algunas de las tablas creadas

```
CREATE TABLE M
(ID_Museo VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Nombre VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '',
Poblacion VARCHAR(20),
Pais VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Museo));

CREATE TABLE E
(ID_Exp VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Nombre VARCHAR(60),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Exp));

CREATE TABLE ME
(ID_Museo VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
ID_Exp VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Fecha DATE,
NDias TINYINT(3),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Museo, ID_Exp, Fecha),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Museo) REFERENCES M (ID_Museo),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Exp) REFERENCES E (ID_Exp));
```

Y aqui algunas inserts utilizadas

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO M (ID_MUSEO,NOMBRE,POBLACION,PAIS)
VALUES ('M1','BELLAS ARTES','BILBAO','ESPANIA'),
        ('M2','REINA SOFIA','MADRID','ESPANIA'),
        ('M3','GUGGENHEIM','BILBAO','ESPANIA');
INSERT IGNORE INTO E (ID_EXP,NOMBRE)
VALUES ('E1','PARIS Y LOS SURREALISTAS'),
        ('E2','BILBAO EN LAS REVISTAS ILUSTRADAS'),
        ('E3','MILLARES EN SILOS'),
        ('E4','LAS TRES DIMENSIONES DEL QUIJOTE'),
        ('E5','HABLANDO CON LAS MANOS'),
        ('E6','IVES KLAIN');

INSERT IGNORE INTO ME (ID_MUSEO,ID_EXP,FECHA,NDIAS)
VALUES ('M1','E1','2013/06/20',90),
        ('M1','E2','2020/02/04',64),
        ('M2','E3','2020/09/14',94),
        ('M2','E4','2020/11/09',90),
        ('M3','E5','2021/03/20',64),
        ('M3','E6','2020/02/01',64);
```

Comment: Buenas, Alejandro, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Puedes incluir la estructura básica de tus tablas (CREATE) y algunos datos de prueba (INSERT) e indicarnos qué quieres hacer exactamente (Enunciado del ejercicio). ¿Quieres actualizar aquellas exposiciones llamadas "Hablando con las manos" en los museos "Guggenheim" o algo así? Lo de quiero ejecutar dos subconsultas así en genérico no aporta mucho a la hora de resolverlo.

Comment: @RubioRic Le agradezco mucho la ayuda para hacer una pregunta mucho mas exacta y no generica. He actualizado la regunta pra que sea algo mas comprensible. Muchas gracias, y perdone las molestias.

Comment: De nada, hombre, ninguna molestia. Mucho mejor ahora. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He modificado ligeramente las sentencias facilitadas para que se vean mejor los nombres de las tablas. He omitido el modificador IGNORE de los INSERT porque no parecía necesario.

```
CREATE TABLE MUSEOS
(ID_Museo VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Nombre VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '',
Poblacion VARCHAR(20),
Pais VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Museo));

CREATE TABLE EXPOSICIONES
(ID_Exp VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Nombre VARCHAR(60),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Exp));

CREATE TABLE EXPOSICIONES_X_MUSEOS
(ID_Museo VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
ID_Exp VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Fecha DATE,
NDias TINYINT(3),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Museo, ID_Exp, Fecha),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Museo) REFERENCES MUSEOS (ID_Museo),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Exp) REFERENCES EXPOSICIONES (ID_Exp));
                                   

INSERT INTO MUSEOS (ID_MUSEO,NOMBRE,POBLACION,PAIS)
VALUES ('M1','BELLAS ARTES','BILBAO','ESPANIA'),
        ('M2','REINA SOFIA','MADRID','ESPANIA'),
        ('M3','GUGGENHEIM','BILBAO','ESPANIA');
                                   
INSERT INTO EXPOSICIONES (ID_EXP,NOMBRE)
VALUES ('E1','PARIS Y LOS SURREALISTAS'),
        ('E2','BILBAO EN LAS REVISTAS ILUSTRADAS'),
        ('E3','MILLARES EN SILOS'),
        ('E4','LAS TRES DIMENSIONES DEL QUIJOTE'),
        ('E5','HABLANDO CON LAS MANOS'),
        ('E6','IVES KLAIN');

INSERT INTO EXPOSICIONES_X_MUSEOS (ID_MUSEO,ID_EXP,FECHA,NDIAS)
VALUES ('M1','E1','2013/06/20',90),
        ('M1','E2','2020/02/04',64),
        ('M2','E3','2020/09/14',94),
        ('M2','E4','2020/11/09',90),
        ('M3','E5','2021/03/20',64),
        ('M3','E6','2020/02/01',64);
```

La consulta que creo que buscas es

```
UPDATE EXPOSICIONES_X_MUSEOS
SET NDIAS = NDIAS + 20
WHERE ID_MUSEO = (SELECT ID_MUSEO FROM MUSEOS WHERE NOMBRE = 'GUGGENHEIM' LIMIT 1)
AND ID_EXP = (SELECT ID_EXP FROM EXPOSICIONES WHERE NOMBRE = 'HABLANDO CON LAS MANOS' LIMIT 1);
```

Si te fijas no hay diferencia entre ejecutar una subconsulta o todas las que quieras. He añadido el LIMIT 1 para que me devuelva el primer registro que encuentre dado que no has declarado los nombres como únicos, con lo cual podríamos obtener varios registros ahí y que se produjera un error

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Si quisieramos actualizar varios museos podríamos sustituir el = por un IN.

Por último, no necesitas invocar el método SUM para que se sumen 20 días, basta con el operador +.

Pues constatar que funciona [aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xfchcJULQTWq78hdt6zGxQ/0)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE MUSEOS
(ID_Museo VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Nombre VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '',
Poblacion VARCHAR(20),
Pais VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Museo));

CREATE TABLE EXPOSICIONES
(ID_Exp VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Nombre VARCHAR(60),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Exp));

CREATE TABLE EXPOSICIONES_X_MUSEOS
(ID_Museo VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
ID_Exp VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Fecha DATE,
NDias TINYINT(3),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Museo, ID_Exp, Fecha),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Museo) REFERENCES MUSEOS (ID_Museo),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Exp) REFERENCES EXPOSICIONES (ID_Exp));
                                   

INSERT INTO MUSEOS (ID_MUSEO,NOMBRE,POBLACION,PAIS)
VALUES ('M1','BELLAS ARTES','BILBAO','ESPANIA'),
        ('M2','REINA SOFIA','MADRID','ESPANIA'),
        ('M3','GUGGENHEIM','BILBAO','ESPANIA');
                                   
INSERT INTO EXPOSICIONES (ID_EXP,NOMBRE)
VALUES ('E1','PARIS Y LOS SURREALISTAS'),
        ('E2','BILBAO EN LAS REVISTAS ILUSTRADAS'),
        ('E3','MILLARES EN SILOS'),
        ('E4','LAS TRES DIMENSIONES DEL QUIJOTE'),
        ('E5','HABLANDO CON LAS MANOS'),
        ('E6','IVES KLAIN');

INSERT INTO EXPOSICIONES_X_MUSEOS (ID_MUSEO,ID_EXP,FECHA,NDIAS)
VALUES ('M1','E1','2013/06/20',90),
        ('M1','E2','2020/02/04',64),
        ('M2','E3','2020/09/14',94),
        ('M2','E4','2020/11/09',90),
        ('M3','E5','2021/03/20',64),
        ('M3','E6','2020/02/01',64);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM EXPOSICIONES_X_MUSEOS;
```

| ID_Museo | ID_Exp | Fecha | NDias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | E1 | 2013-06-20 | 90 |
| M1 | E2 | 2020-02-04 | 64 |
| M2 | E3 | 2020-09-14 | 94 |
| M2 | E4 | 2020-11-09 | 90 |
| M3 | E5 | 2021-03-20 | 64 |
| M3 | E6 | 2020-02-01 | 64 |

---

**Query #2**

```
UPDATE EXPOSICIONES_X_MUSEOS
SET NDIAS = NDIAS + 20
WHERE ID_MUSEO = (SELECT ID_MUSEO FROM MUSEOS WHERE NOMBRE = 'GUGGENHEIM' LIMIT 1)
AND ID_EXP = (SELECT ID_EXP FROM EXPOSICIONES WHERE NOMBRE = 'HABLANDO CON LAS MANOS' LIMIT 1);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT * FROM EXPOSICIONES_X_MUSEOS;
```

| ID_Museo | ID_Exp | Fecha | NDias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | E1 | 2013-06-20 | 90 |
| M1 | E2 | 2020-02-04 | 64 |
| M2 | E3 | 2020-09-14 | 94 |
| M2 | E4 | 2020-11-09 | 90 |
| M3 | E5 | 2021-03-20 | 84 |
| M3 | E6 | 2020-02-01 | 64 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xfchcJULQTWq78hdt6zGxQ/0)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, esto es justo lo que estaba buscando.

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacer el UPDATE en MySql sin usar subconsultas. En una sola query vinculo las tablas con INNER JOIN y filtro utilizando la claúsula WHERE:

```
UPDATE ME
INNER JOIN M ON ME.ID_Museo = M.ID_Museo
INNER JOIN E ON ME.ID_Exp = E.ID_Exp
SET ME.NDIAS = ME.NDIAS + 20
WHERE E.Nombre = 'Hablando con las manos' AND  M.Nombre = 'Guggenheim';
```